# apply returns weird result

Tags: r, apply

I have a r data frame like

```r
df <- data.frame(ruleA = c('N', 'N', -1), ruleB = c(0, 0, -1))
```

where element 'N' passes rule A and element 0 passes rule B, and I want to apply a function by row to see if each observation(row) passed all rules.

At first I tried

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x %in% c('N', 0)))
```

and I was expecting `(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` but it actually returns `(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`.

And the thing is when I tried

```r
apply(df[1:2, ], 1, function(x) all(x %in% c('N', 0)))
```

it returns `(TRUE, TRUE)`. Why this happens?

Then I tried more like

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) x %in% c('N', 0))
```

and expecting

```
(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

but it returns

```
(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

And again when I apply with `df[1:2, ]` only, it returns the correct result. What's going wrong with element 0? Please anyone help.

It seems replacing -1 by 1-9 avoids the white-space, so how digits involved in the apply process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear why this happens but if you try to debug the problem step-by-step, there is a whitespace with 0 when you pass `df` to `apply`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) browser())

Browse[1]> x
# ruleA ruleB 
#  "N"  " 0"
```

but that is not the case when you pass `df[1:2, ]`

```
apply(df[1:2,], 1, function(x) browser())
Browse[1]> x
#ruleA ruleB 
#  "N"   "0"
```

that's why it works in your second attempt.

An option is to remove the whitespace using `trimws` and then it gives you expected output

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) all(trimws(x) %in% c('N', 0)))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

There is also another alternative which will allow you to ignore all the issues with `apply` directly using `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df == 'N' | df == 0) == ncol(df)
```

Comment: Just noticed the whitespace issue, too. Appears to be a bug related to single integers. It's not an issue for -1 or 10, but it is for 1-9.

Comment: Ok I got the point and figured out replacing -1 by 1-9 works. The rowSums solution works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Item number 2 of `c('N', 0)` is not numeric. Coerced to "0". "0" not identical to `0`. Although `0 == "0" returns`TRUE`,`identical(0, "0") returns `FALSE`. The `apply` function will always coerce to common class.

There is a gotcha that I'm not clear on the origin. Take a look at this:

```
apply(df,1,str)
 Named chr [1:2] "N" " 0"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "ruleA" "ruleB"
 Named chr [1:2] "N" " 0"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "ruleA" "ruleB"
 Named chr [1:2] "-1" "-1"
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "ruleA" "ruleB"
```

For some reason the coercion of `0` to character is adding an extra space.

Comment: It is actually equal right? `0 == "0"`

Answer (score 0):

another way of solving:

```
df$ruleA == 'N' & df$ruleB == 0
```

With the `case_when` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(
    PassBothRules = case_when(ruleA == "N" & ruleB == 0 ~ TRUE,
                              TRUE ~ FALSE)
  )
```

Some ideas to think about, the way the rowSums solution is written, it sort of assumes two rows, which would give potential false positives if you had more columns and those columns contained N's or 0's.

In your test data, it's good practice to include all the variations of the rules, so in your case, I'd do: triggers both rules, only the first, only the second, neither, ex:

```
df <- data.frame(ruleA = c('N', 'N', -1, 2), 
                 ruleB = c(0, 2, 0, 2),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

(edit: I've added stringsAsFactors=FALSE to ensure no extra uncertainty is introduced from data.frames default behavior converting ruleA to factors)

Comment: you can always subset columns in `rowSums` solution if you have more columns. `rowSums(df[1:2] == 'N' | df[1:2] == 0) == 2`